# TSQL to select the last 10 rows from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains 300 million rows, and a clustered index on the [DataDate] column.

How do I select the last 10 rows of this table (I want to find the most recent date in the table)?

Database: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

**Update**

The answers below work perfectly - but only if there is a clustered index on [DataDate]. The table is, after all, 300 million rows, and a naive query would end up taking hours to execute rather than seconds. The query plan is using the clustered index on [DataDate] to get results within a few tens of milliseconds.

Comment: How many columns do you want? All? DataDate only?

Comment: All the columns, sorted by [DataDate].

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189463.aspx)

```
SELECT TOP(10) [DataDate] FROM YourTable ORDER BY [DataDate] DESC
```

Comment: Correct because best use of an index

Comment: @Gravitas: the timestamp is reverse: this was answered "16 mins ago" vs "15 mins ago". This is more correct because it selects one column: SELECT * will use a slightly different plan

Comment: @gbn: The requirements here is to obtain the last 10 rows, not the last 10 `DataDate` values... That means I became later but with the right answer ;)

Comment: @Akram Shahda. Okay, marked this as the answer. There are a lot of very honest and fair people on SO, I'm impressed.

Answer (score 12):

[TOP (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) specifies that only the first set of rows will be returned from the query result. The set of rows can be either a number or a percent of the rows. The `TOP` expression can be used in `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `MERGE`, and `DELETE` statements.

```
SELECT TOP(10) *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY DataDate DESC
```

Comment: Thanks - this works perfectly, despite the fact that the table has 300 million rows (the query plan is using the clustered index on [DataDate]).

Answer (score 2):

Do a reverse sort using ORDER BY and use TOP.